# Fair die being rolled repeatedly

Tags: probability

A fair die is rolled repeatedly, and let $X$ record the number of the roll when the 1st  $6$  appears.  A game is played as follows.  A player pays  \$1  to play the game.  If $X\leq 5$ , then he loses the dollar.   If  $6 \le X \le 10$, then he gets his dollar back plus \$1.  And if $X  >  10$, then he gets his dollar back plus \$2 .  Is this a fair game?  If not, whom does it favour?

I think that that it is not a fair game because it solely depends on whether the first number is $6$ which is a $\frac{1}{6}$ chance. But I don't know how to prove this further.

Comment: This should help you. This situation/ game is best modelled by a geometric distribution. What you can do is find the probabilities of each event using the formulas described on the wikipedia page and then use the expected value formula $E(X)=\sum x\cdot p(x)$ and if E(X) is not 0, then the game is not fair. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y$ be the **net** amount the "player"  wins. Then $Y$ is a random variable that takes on the possible values $-1$, $1$, and $2$.

The probability that $Y=2$ is the probability of $10$ non-sixes in a row. For those are precisely the conditions under which the player has a net gain of $2$ dollars. Thus $\Pr(Y=2)=(5/6)^{10}$.

The probability that $Y=1$ is the probability of between $5$ and $9$ non-sixes in a row. This is the probability of $5$ non-sixes minus the probability of $10$ non-sixes. Thus $\Pr(Y=1)=(5/6)^5-(5/6)^{10}$.

The probability that $Y=-1$ is $1$ minus the probability of $5$ non-sixes in a row. Thus $\Pr(Y=-1)=1-(5/6)^5$.

Now we calculate the expectation $E(Y)$ of $Y$. This is 
$$(-1)\Pr(Y=-1)+(1)\Pr(Y=1)+(2)\Pr(Y=2).\tag{1}$$

If (1) is $\gt 0$, the game favours the player, and if it is $\lt 0$ it favours the opponent.

**Remark:** It is a little easier to work with the **gross** win, which is any of $0$, $1$, or $2$. It turns out that the expectation is remarkably simple. You may glimpse some of that simplicity by doing "algebra" on (1) instead of feeding it immediately into a calculator.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of failures before the first success is modeled by the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution). So you have to figure out what the expectation of the random variable with payout:
$$
\begin{matrix}
-1 & P(X \leq 5)\\
1 &  P(6 \leq X \leq 10)\\
3 & P(X \geq 11)
\end{matrix}
$$

Where $X$ is geometrically distributed with probability of success is the probability of seeing a $6$ on a six-sided die. If the expectation of the payout is 0, the game is fair; otherwise *someone* expects to make a profit in the long run.

**Update**
To answer the comment. Since this is discrete, you'll have to calculate three sets of probabilities. The first is $X \leq 5$ which is made up of $X = 0, X = 1, X = 2, X = 3, X = 4,$ and $X = 5$. For all of these possibilities, the player loses a dollar. Now for $X = 6, X = 7,\ldots,X = 10$, the player gains two dollars. At this point we have the sum of all the probabilities for $X \leq 10$. So the probability that $X \geq 11$ is just 1 (total probability of everything) minus the running sum we needed for the first two sets.

At this point we have three numbers: $p_1$ which is the sum for $X=0$ to $X=5$, $p_2$ which is the middle bucket, and $p_3 = 1 - p_1 - p_2$. Now we know that $p_1$ of the time, the player loses a dollar, $p_2$ of the time the player wins a dollar, and $p_3$ of the time the player wins two dollars. Now, is the expectation = 0 or not? That determines if it is "fair" or not.

Comment: What i did was calculate the probability that x is less than 6 and it turned out to be where the game does not favor the player because there is less than .5 chance that the player will win and not lose. Is that correct? @avraham

Comment: I expanded my answer; I hope it helps make it clearer to you.

Answer (score 0):

The probability the number is $X$ is $(\dfrac{5}{6})^{X-1}\cdot\dfrac{1}{6}$

Therefore the expected gains of a game is 
$$\sum_{X=6}^{\infty}(\dfrac{5}{6})^{X-1}\cdot\dfrac{1}{6}+2\sum_{X=11}^\infty(\dfrac{5}{6})^{X-1}\cdot\dfrac{1}{6}=\dfrac{1}{6}(\sum_{X=6}^\infty(\dfrac{5}{6})^{X-1}+2\sum_{X=11}^\infty(\dfrac{5}{6})^{X-1})=$$

$$\dfrac{1}{6}(18-(1+\frac{5}{6}+((\frac{5}{6})^2\dots(\frac{5}{6})^4)+2(1+\frac{5}{6}+((\frac{5}{6})^2\dots(\frac{5}{6})^9)=$$

$$\frac{1}{6}(18-\frac{4651}{1296}-2(\frac{50700551}{10077696}))\approx0.72$$ so no, it isn't worth it to play.

Comment: But isn't .72 more than .5? or is it because it does not equal 1?

Comment: The cost for the game is 1 dollar and in average you will get .72 dollars, that is why it is not a good choice to play the game

Comment: To write down the series, one should use anything but X as a dummy index.